# Sorting and deleting rows. Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, rowdeleting

I tried to work with macros that should

1. sort p-values in column H
2. delete all the rows with p-values `>=0.05`
3. fill column I with "B - E", I mean `I2=B2-E2`; `I3=B3-E3` et cetera
4. sort by column I

This macros was created by Jeeped:

```
Sub sort1()
    Dim m As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        'delete rows 1:6
        .Range("1:6").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        'new column header for column I
        Range("I1") = "diff"

        'sort A:I on column H (ascending)
        With .Range("A:I")
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(8), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        End With

        'find >=0.05
        m = Application.Match(0.05, .Range("H:H"), 0)
        If IsError(m) Then m = Application.Match(0.05, .Range("H:H"))

        'delete rows (>=0.05):<bottom of worksheet>
        .Range(.Cells(m, "A"), .Cells(.rows.Count, "A")).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        'new formula for column I data range
        .Range("I2:I" & m - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]-RC[-4]"

        'calculate (actually unnecessary, putting in new formulas forces true calculation)
        .Calculate

        'sort A:I on column I (ascending)
        With .Range("A:I")
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(9), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes  
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

It worked before but now it stops on the string

```
.Range(.Cells(m, "A"), .Cells(.rows.Count, "A")).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

It says

> Run-time error '13':
> Type mismatch

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the data that this sub is processing it is difficult to guess why are you getting that error. However, my bet is that the `Application.Match` function can't find any values in column `H` that are less than or equal to `0.05`, so `m = #N/A` and you can't pass `#N/A` to the `.Cells()` property.

If that is the case (you can check if it is in the immediate window after the error appears), try deleting the rows and sorting only if `MATCH` was successful:

```
Sub sort1()
'begin your code here

'find >=0.05
m = Application.Match(0.05, .Range("H:H"), 0)
If IsError(m) Then m = Application.Match(0.05, .Range("H:H"))

If Not IsError(m) Then
    'delete rows (>=0.05):<bottom of worksheet>
    .Range(.Cells(m, "A"), .Cells(.rows.Count, "A")).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    'new formula for column I data range
    .Range("I2:I" & m - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]-RC[-4]"

    'calculate (actually unnecessary, putting in new formulas forces true calculation)
    .Calculate
End If

'sort A:I on column I (ascending)
With .Range("A:I")
    .Sort Key1:=.Columns(9), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With

'Continue your code here
End Sub
```

**P.S,** your code currently doesn't do exactly what you said all the times:

You wanted to delete all rows that are bigger than or equal to `0.05`, but if you didn't have a value that is exactly equal to `0.05`, and had values like:`(0, ..., 0.048, 0.049, 0.051, 0.052, ...)` in your `H` column, then this line of code:

```
If IsError(m) Then m = Application.Match(0.05, .Range("H:H"))
```

will find the largest value that is less than or equal to `0.05`, which is `0.049` in our hypothetical data.
Then this line of code:

```
.Range(.Cells(m, "A"), .Cells(.rows.Count, "A")).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

will delete the rows which had the values from `0.049` to the end (`0.049` included).

You code is deleting one extra value more than what you wanted, but since you said it worked before as you wanted, I didn't change it.

If you want to correct this behavior, you need to add one to `m` the second time you use `MATCH`:

```
If IsError(m) Then m = Application.Match(0.05, .Range("H:H")) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work because it was number as text in H column

Comment: @ЕкатеринаСамойлова What didn't work. What unexpected result did you get?

Comment: The original code gave error, because in H column in sheet was number as text

Comment: @ЕкатеринаСамойлова Then I suggest you edit your H column to store numbers as numbers. If that is not achievable, and if all values in your H column are stored as text, then you can change the lookup value in the `MATCH` function to look for text, like this: `m = Application.Match("0.05", .Range("H:H"))`